# Accessing the first <ul> element under the div

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

I am new to web scraping and I was trying to create a simple web scraper using a tutorial. I did that, however, I wanted to try implementing another feature on my own. In the link (https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/), I was trying to fetch all the bullet points from the 'guidelines' (On the right side of the page). Right now, I am able to scrape and get all the information from the 'guidelines', 'info', and 'relatedReddits'. However, I was only trying to get the information from the 'guidelines'. Does anyone know how I can modify my code to access only the first ul tag under the div because right now, it accesses all. Thanks for stopping by.

[image]

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const getPostTitles = async () => {
  try{
    const {data} = await axios.get('https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/');
    //console.log(data);

    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const guidelines = [];
    const postTitles = [];

    // to get text in form of array
    $('p.title > a').each((idx, el) => {
      const postTitle = $(el).text();
      postTitles.push(postTitle);
    });

    $('.md ul li').each((idx, el) => {
      const guideline = $(el).text();
      guidelines.push(guideline);
    });

    console.log(guidelines);

    return postTitles;

  }
  catch(error){
    throw error;
  }
}

getPostTitles()
.then((postTitles) => console.log(postTitles))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.md').find('ul').first().each((i, el) => {
      const guideline = $(el).text();
      guidelines.push(guideline);
    });
```

This was the solution for anyone that comes here to look.